# Populate second dropdown based on first dropdown using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to select first the `source_type` and then it automatically populate the `location` based on the `source_type`

view file

```
    <select name="source_type" id="source_type">
       <option value="">Source Type</option>
       <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
       <option value="External">External</option>
    </select>

    <select name="location" id="location">
       <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>

    $('#source_type').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: 'source_type'+$(this).val(),
            url: 'get_sources_location',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#source_location').val(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

..controller

```
    public function get_sources_location()
    {
        $source_type = $this->input->post('source_type');

        $this->load->model('documents_model');
        $results = $this->documents_model->get_locations();
        echo $results;
    }
```

..model

```
    public function get_locations()
    {
     $query = $this
                ->db
                ->select('location')
                ->where('classification', $source_type = $this->input->post('source_type'))
                ->get('sources_location');

     $data = array();

     foreach ($query->result() as $row)
     {
         $data = $row->location;
     }
     return $data;
   }
```

Comment: Call AJAX function on onChange event of first dropdown, get response and load it as options in second dropdown.

Comment: onchange of first dropdown call contoller function which give you data for your second dropdown by ajax

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

**HTML CODE**

```
<select name="source_type" id="source_type" onchange="populateLocation(this.value)">
   <option value="">Source Type</option>
   <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
   <option value="External">External</option>
</select>

<select name="location" id="location">
   <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE USING JQUERY**

```
function populateLocation(source_type_value){
            if(source_type_value !=''){
                /*
                    Pass your source type value to controller function which will return you json for your
                    loaction dropdown
                */
                var url = 'controller/function/'+ source_type_value; // 
                $.get(url, function(data) {
                 var $select = $('location');
                 // removing all previously filled option
                 $select.empty();
                 for (var propt in data) {
                        $select.append($('<option />', {
                            value: propt,
                            text: data[propt]
                        }));
                 }

            }
        }
```

**JSON FORMAT** to be returned from controller

```
{"":"Select","1":"New york","2":"London","3":"Mumbai"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put an AJAX Function like this,

```
$("#source_type").change(function(){

  $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     data : 'source_id='+ $(this).val(),
     url : 'controller/method',
     success : function(data){
                 $('#location').val(data);
     }
 });
});
```

In controller, put a method to get the values,

```
public function getLocations() {

     $source_id = $this->input->post('source_id');

     // Call the model function and get all the locations based on the source type id

     // Populate the dropdown options here

     echo $result;
}
```

Comment: wondering why its not returning record. here's my code.
http://pastebin.com/nkWNaGqe

Answer (score 0):

attach a `change` event handler to your first DD and send an ajax call to the server to fetch data. In the success callback of the ajax call populate the second DD. Below is a simple proof of concept

```
$("#source_type").change(function(e)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:'/echo/json',
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            $("<option/>",{text:'google',value:'google'}).appendTo("#location");
        }
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W2Tjt/)

Comment: working but data on the dropdown are separated (,) only 1 line.